# Syntax for separating variable declaration and anonymous class instantiation in android/java

Tags: java, android

According to Android Studio, instead of doing this:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

        }
    };
```

I can do this:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mCallback;

{
    mCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

        }
    };
}
```

I think the second syntax option is much prettier, but I don't understand why it requires curly braces around the anonymous class instantiation. My understanding is that curly braces locally scope the enclosed code, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those brackets around field initialization are called [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). Everything you put inside is executed with constructor. You can execute any code within it:

```
class Main {
    int a = 1;
    int b;

    {
        b = 1;
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I prefer the first approach. Initializer blocks introduce unnecessary complexity and confusion. For example this is a compile error:

```
Object a = b.toString();
Object b = "";
```

While this will fail at runtime:

```
Object c;
Object d;

{
    d = c.toString();
    c = "";
}
```

It becomes even more complex when you add regular constructors and superclasses to the mix.

Comment: This is very useful! 3 years of android development, never knew this, shame on me

Comment: Thanks! Why do you say initializer blocks introduce unnecessary complexity and confusion? Is it just because people put them far away from the declaration?

Comment: @WWH Not many people know about it and misinterpret what they do. Even people familiar with it would have trouble telling in which order they are executed. It's easier to reason about code without them.

Answer (score 0):

When using anonymous classes, you include the code for class definition in curly braces after the new NewClass statement. This is useful when this is a one-off class that you wouldn't be needing again. If you will use this class frequently, you may want to create a separate class file for its definition.

You can do the same to method definitions.